# Signed Decimal Binary to Decimal conversion

Tags: algorithms

I have tried to convert signed binary number, -11.875, to unsigned value.
I am not sure about where to add the carry bit taking 2's complement of binary -11.875.
The carry bit should be added with the decimal part or the RHS side of -11.875?

Comment: I have tried by first converting -11.875 to binary which is equivalent to 10101.111. Add then taking 2's complement to find the unsigned value.

Comment: Which carry bit ??

Comment: I am not sure that $2$'s complement are defined for fractional numbers. Do you mean a fixed-point representation ?